# Is there a way to share Vim command history?

Tags: command-history

Can I share Vim command history across instances in real time?

By that I mean what people do in bash this way:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

That is, when I run a command `echo test1` in one shell, and then press <kbd>Up</kbd> in another one, I see `echo test1`. (To be precise, one has to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before <kbd>Up</kbd> for it to work.)

Is this possible with Vim? At first I thought using the `+clientserver` option would work out. But that seems to be something else.

Comment: Related question: [_How is command history resolved between multiple instances of Vim?_](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/361/24)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command history is stored in the *viminfo* file (`:help viminfo`). Usually that is read on startup and written on exit, but you could explicitly persist and sync between Vim instances with a combination of `:wviminfo` and `:rviminfo`. Note that this will sync the entire information; i.e. also register contents, marks, buffer lists, etc.

Comment: http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-17.3

Answer (score 1):

In Vim the closest you can get is (as Ingo's answer and Christian's comment mentioned) is:

```
augroup viminfo
    autocmd!
    autocmd FocusLost   * wviminfo
    autocmd FocusGained * rviminfo
augroup end
```

It's important to realize that the `Focus*` autocommands aren't always run when you use Vim from a terminal, especially not if you're using tmux or screen. You should test this first by using `:au FocusLost :echoerr "Focus lost!"`.

As far as I know there is no good work-around if these autocommands don't work for you. Using other events (such as `CursorHold`) seem problematic to me due to timing issues that will almost certainly crop up.

---

Neovim comes with "ShaDa", which is a replacement for Vim's viminfo system. One aspect where it's better is merging files from different instances, and while it doesn't directly support syncing between multiple instances ([yet](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/999)), this seems to [work well for at least one Neovim developer](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/3oyy7m/shada_has_landed/cw1vv9n/):

```
augroup shada
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorHold * rshada | wshada
augroup end
```

See `:help shada-merging` for details on the merging process.

Comment: Note: I think Vim 8 also introduce merging functionality because it timestamps the commands entered. See `:h viminfo-timestamp`

Comment: I tried it on my system before posting this answer @ChristianBrabandt, and it didn't seem to work very well. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: perhaps a bug? would need a good reproducible example at @vim-dev list